# List<T>.Insert vs Stack<T>.Push

Tags: c#, .net, performance, generics

I am returning a `IList<T>` from a method.

In the calling class I want to insert a value at the start of the list/stack.

Inserting a value in `List<T>` is slower than pushing a value in `Stack<T>`. But to use stack I need to unbox it.

So the question is which one is better, unbox or using `Insert` in `List<T>`? Which one is costlier?

```
class MyClass 
{
}

IList<MyClass> Method1()
{
}

class MainClass
{
   List<MyClass> list = (List<MyClass>)Method1();
   list.insert(0,new MyClass{...}); //insert at the start. 

   Stack<MyClass> stack = (Stack<MyClass>)Method1();
   stack.Push(new MyClass{...}); //insert at the start
}
```

Comment: [`Stack`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3278tedw.aspx)'s do no implement the `IList<T>` interface so that should always fail.

Comment: Stack<T> does not implement IList<T>, so this whole question is moot. IList<T> says "I act like a list, so feel free to access me via index if you like." Stack<T> says "I'm a stack. Access me from the top *only*." Kind of a problem, no?

Comment: I am sorry.I did not run the code but it compiled and wrote the question on SO.My Bad.

Comment: @Mangesh: THe List version above won't compile - the Stack version would compile, but fail at runtime every time.

Comment: @Reed : Thanks Reed you are correct.I modified the question.

Comment: @Mangesh: The problem is that one of the above, and possibly both (the Stack one always), will fail at runtime... A conversion routine (ie: casting to `List<T>`) will only work if the actual implementation inside Method1 is the same type as the class you're converting to...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not unboxing here in either version (though the first won't compile.. and the second would always fail at runtime) -

However, in either case, if you do the conversion, *it will only work if the actual underlying implementation is that class*.

If your method returns an `IList<T>`, I'd strongly suggest sticking to `IList<T>` members.  Converting the results to a `List<T>` or `Stack<T>` (ie: whatever the internal implementation happens to be - which is not `Stack<T>` since that doesn't implement `IList<T>`) is very dangerous.

The main reason to return `IList<T>` is to purposefully allow you to later change the internal implementation.  `Method1`, internally, might later change from `List<T>` to some other `IList<T>`, which would cause your code to break unexpectedly.

That being said, if you know that the internal implementation may be a certain type, you can check for it - but I wouldn't blindly cast.

Comment: I've deleted my answer, which suggested test-casting to `Stack<T>`, which is impossible as `Stack<T>` does not implement `IList<T>`. Your strong suggestion is actually a requirement :)

Comment: @sixlettervariables: Yeah, I know - I had also put an edit in mentioning that - I figured this was an example, as **neither** case in the original question  will compile ;)

Answer (score 1):

> *Inserting a value in `List<T>` is slower than pushing a value in `Stack<T>`.*

**Yes**, for the reason that inserting in a list is a different operation from pushing to a stack. When you insert a new item into the middle of a list, then entire array that comes afterward has to be shifted by one. This is an O(n) operation. Pushing to a stack just adds the value to the end of the internal array. This is cheap - O(1). The comparable operation is `List<T>.Add`

But I do think there is a misunderstanding here as to when to use which. There is no difference between a `List<T>` and `Stack<T>` implementation-wise or performance-wise for the same operation. The only difference is in the features each collection exposes. You can mimic popping to `Stack<T>` in `List<T>` by (adding to end of the list and by) removing from the end: `list.RemoveAt(list.Count - 1)`. It's how you want to use it that matters here. If you are going to use `List<T>` as a `Stack<T>` then discard the former and always use the latter. It makes your intent clearer. You're less error prone in future thus.

> *But to use stack I need to unbox it.*

There is no unboxing here. Unboxing is when you cast from a reference type (`object`, `IList<T>`) to a value type (like structs, enums). `Stack<T>` is not a value type, hence there is no unboxing. Its just reference conversion, preserving the identity. It's as cheap as it can get.

> *So the question is which one is better, unbox or using `Insert` in `List<T>`? Which one is costlier?*

- Your second code doesn't work. `Stack<T>` isn't `IList<T>`. So you have only one choice left.
- `Insert` is definitely costlier, but that alone doesn't mean you should use a `Stack<T>`. `Stack<T>` doesn't give you random access via indexes, removal from middle etc. But if all you need is a `Stack<T>`, stick to it. `List<T>` is too general purpose with which you can do lot of things.

Bottom line: you either return `Stack<T>` and use it (better performance), or you return `IList<T>` and use it (more features). In the end, decide based on use first.